# Radial ordering in CFT

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

Consider the following quantum two-point function (without assuming radial time ordering),
$$\begin{align}
    \langle 0 | \hat{T}(y)\hat{T}(z) |0 \rangle
    & = \sum_{n,m}y^{-(m+2)}z^{-(n+2)}\langle 0 | L_m L_n |0\rangle \\
    & = \sum_{n\leq -2}\sum_{m\geq 2}y^{-(m+2)}z^{-(n+2)}\langle 0 | L_m L_n |0\rangle \\
    & = \sum_{m\geq 2} y^{-(m+2)}z^{-(-m+2)}\frac{c}{12}m(m^2-1) \\
    & = \frac{c/2}{(y-z)^4}
\end{align}\tag{1}$$
where I have used the Virasoro algebra.

The result matches with the statistical correlator $\langle T(y)T(z)\rangle$ obtained from a (hypothetical) functional integral.

My understanding is that quantum and statistical correlation functions are supposed to be related as follows,
$$ \langle 0 | \mathsf{R}[\hat{T}(y)\hat{T}(z)] |0 \rangle = \langle T(y)T(z)\rangle\tag{2}$$ where $\mathsf{R}$ denotes the radial ordering operator. The above calculation, however, suggests that
$$ \langle 0 | \hat{T}(y)\hat{T}(z) |0 \rangle = \langle T(y)T(z)\rangle.\tag{3}$$
What happened to the radial ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The main point is that the sum in OP's eq. (1) is only [(absolutely) convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence) if $|y|>|z|$, i.e. if OP's LHS $$\hat{T}(y)\hat{T}(z)~=~{\cal R}[\hat{T}(y)\hat{T}(z)]$$ is radially ordered.
2. (Absolute) convergence is needed in the last equality of OP's eq. (1) if we want to sum (a third derivative of) a geometric series and obtain OP's RHS.
3. Moreover, note the following consistency check: If we include a radial ordering ${\cal R}$ on the LHS of OP's eq. (1), then both the LHS and the RHS are manifestly symmetric under $y\leftrightarrow z$.

Comment: Why do we need to be able to “sum a third derivative” of that series?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following point 2. Why can't we allow conditional convergence here? Is absolute convergence strictly necessary for some reason?

Comment: In QFT we perform conditionally convergent sums/integrals all the time and this does not seem to bother anyone; e.g. $\int\frac{d^d k}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{e^{ik x}}{k^2+m^2}$

Comment: Consider for simplicity the case $y,z\geq 0$. Then the sum is non-negative, and the different notions of convergence coincide.